# Luis.ai migration error "Endpoint keys were assigned by collaborators to your apps and you have no access to them."

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

**While performing Luis.ai applications migration at both www.luis.ai and preview.luis.ai**

We start the operation by this dialog:
[image]

---

**we are getting following error:**

> BadArgument: Endpoint keys were assigned by collaborators to your apps
>   and you have no access to them. Either remove these keys or get
>   access. Keys: {keyPath: userassigned, region: WUS, appId: 1234567890},
>   {keyPath: userassigned, region: WUS, appId: 1234567891}

See also screenshot from Notifications: [image]

---

**Unfortunately we don't see in the list of Luis applications in the portal any with the appId from the error. We have discovered the mentioned appIds in our database from the time when we were using Luis applications with same appIds but we have thought we already deleted mentioned Luis applications at the beginning of 10/2019. All the Luis application we have used or we are using are private.**

**If the Luis applications still exist *somewhere* is there a way to force remove the "endpoint keys" that were created by account that is actually logged-in?**

---

Thank @ranusharao for your advice:

I was able to follow mentioned [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/42027) issue. However I ended up the same way as user jbeltranluna 8 days ago. For now in the Github thread it is not clear what to do next.

I also tried all three suggested options "apps-Get application info API", "permissions-Update access list API", "apps-Removes an assigned LUIS azure accounts" and in all cases I ended up with following error for both West US and West Europe

```
"error": { "code": "BadArgument", 
"message": "Cannot find an application with the ID 8b1bd3aa-5ffd-47c7-9f61-f9888e97f364." }
```

---

I'm not sure which user has created mentioned LUIS apps. Could the problem be that if we deleted mentioned apps in 10/2019 that we just removed collaborator role of our current account and the apps still exist in other profile? If at the same time the assigned API key is from current account then this is why the migration is blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be similar to [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/42027) Github issue. Going by the error, what you could do is either remove all the collaborators or the keys from every account and then manage the collaborators.

- Try running [apps - Get application info](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c37) API by adding your app ID to see if you get any information about the application(if its deleted or still exists).
- You can use [permissions - Update access list](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/58fcce825aca2f08a4104344) API to remove all collaborators at once or you can also use [apps - Removes an assigned LUIS azure accounts](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5be32554f8591db3a86232e1) API from an application.

Note: For the given case, **it seems to be a bug related to LUIS app ID's preventing migration even though the apps are deleted**. The fix for this has been pushed in the current release. You can try to migrate and see if you are able to do it successfully without any issues.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I updated the question. Unfortunately I don't see any resolution yet.

Comment: @FerdinandFejskid it seems like its a bug related to LUIS app ID's preventing migration even though the apps are deleted. The fix should be out in the next release.

Comment: We have also asked same question in "General inquiry through User Voice" [tickets@cognitive.uservoice.com] and we received at November 18, 2019 6:25 PM following message "The fix for this issue has been pushed in today's release. Can you try to migrate and see if you are successfully able to without any issues?". And fortunately after mentioned fix the migration finally worked.

Comment: @FerdinandFejskid yes I had updated the answer in the note once the fix was pushed in this week's release. Glad that its working for you.